# Is there any alternative for function fn:parse-xml-fragment using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to this XSLT world and we have a situation where We wanted to use a function `fn:parse-xml-fragment()` which is supported by XSLT version 3.0.

However, in our framework we are still at XSLT version 2.0 and not allowed to upgrade the `saxon.jar` to version 9.6.
Is there any alternative way we could achieve the same result as this function however in XSLT version 2.0?

Comment: I changed the version of the target XSLT. Otherwise the question wouldn't make sense. If I did a mistake, feel free to reverse the edit.

Answer (score 2):

That function is an XPath 3.0/3.1 function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment so you will find it in XSLT processors supporting XPath 3. Depending on your Saxon version and edition it might be possible to use it if you use `version="3.0"` in your stylesheet, even if you have a version and/or edition of Saxon that doesn't support the final XSLT 3.0 specification (e.g. Saxon 9.8 is the first major Saxon release to implement the final XSLT 3 spec but XPath 3 functions like `parse-xml-fragment` are also supported in Saxon 9.7 if you use `version="3.0"` in your XSLT code, if I remember that right).

You haven't told us which processor and version and edition exactly you use, it might be possible to use or implement it as an extension function.

There is also David Carlisle's HTML parser https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl in pure XSLT 2 which can be used (or at least abused) as an XML (fragment) parser if you use `false()` for the third argument, for instance the stylesheet

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:dpc="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[h2 = 'Test']/ul/li">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:value-of select="count(dpc:htmlparse(., '', false())/node())"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/948Fn5t/2 finds the right number of child nodes in the fragments used as input there (e.g.

```
        <li><![CDATA[<foo>foo 1</foo><bar>bar 1</bar><foo>foo 2</foo>]]></li>
        <li><![CDATA[text<element/>text<element>...</element>text]]></li>
```

counts 3 and 5 nodes), the same that `parse-xml-fragment` does in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFH with Saxon 9.8.

You will find however that the `htmlparse` function might parse mal-formed markup while the `parse-xml-fragment` function will give you an error for anything not following the XML rules for an external parsed entity.